# symfony sonata limit results (max)

Tags: symfony

how to set a limt of results with the object image.
i just want to have on result for the listmapper.

i know '_sort_by', but does exist a maximun results that i can put to my listmapper ???
thanks

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

```
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name', null, array('route' => array('name' => 'show')))
        ->add('country')
        ->add('category')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('organisation', null, array('route' => array('name' => 'show')))
        ->add('competition',  null, array('route' => array('name' => 'show')))
        ->add('image')
        ->add('created')
        ->add('updated')
        ->add('_action', null, array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

ps: like add(image', null, array('limit' => 1))
but it's not working

Comment: Do you know use `$this->datagridValues = array(
                '_page'       => 1,
                '_per_page'   => 50,
                /** '_sort_order' => 'DESC',      // sort direction */

            );` ?

Comment: no, it's not working - sorry. I mean, i just want to have 1 entity 'image' from this list mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method createQuery() to change the query used to generate the list, here is an example :

```
class YourAdmin extends AbstractAdmin {

    // ...

    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
       $query = parent::createQuery($context);
       $query
           ->setFirstResult( $offset )
           ->setMaxResults( $limit )
       ;
       return $query;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: what valor in $offset and $limit ?? to have just 16 per page

Comment: I Don't know how to fix it, i want to have only 16 results by page